# Place an image for photo form button in Zend form

Tags: forms, zend-framework, upload, image

I have created a form by Zend form that uploads pictures in jpg and png format. however, the form generates a default button and text that reads "no file chosen". How can I place my own designed button image and remove the default text for this form?

```
$photo = new Zend_Form_Element_File('photo');
$photo->addValidator('Count', false, 1)
->addValidator('Size', false, 200*1024)
->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,png');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use `Zend_Form_Element_Buttom` if you want to use an image.

Just make sure you pass in `type=submit` and you can use the `style=""` attribute to set your image.
You can pass in these using:

```
setAttribs(array('type'=>'submit', 'style'=> array('image' => 'image.png')));
```

I think this syntax is correct, but I'm sure I have the incorrect stlye attributes.

[MDN Button Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Answer (score 1):

```
$photo->setDecorators(array(
            array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'my_upload_button.phtml', 'abc' => $some_parameter)
        );
```

then inside

my_upload_button.phtml do your own style, here is mine

```
<?php
$image = $this->element->getAttrib('class');//prendi il nome del file
$this->element->setAttrib('class', '');//cancella la class
?>

<td class="nome_campo">
<label for="<?php echo $this->element->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $this->element->getLabel(); ?></label></td>
<td class="valore_campo" colspan="1">
<?php echo $this->content; ?>

<?php if ($this->element->hasErrors()): ?>

    <span class="error">
        <?php echo $this->formErrors($this->element->getMessages()); ?>
    </span>

<?php endif; ?>
<p class="hint"><?php echo $this->element->getDescription() ?></p>
<b>
<?php
```